# Listing children of an ABC in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I am using Django 1.3.1 and I have the following piece of models:

```
class masterData(models.Model):
     uid = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)

     class Meta:
          abstract = True;

class Type1(masterData):
     pass;

class Type2(masterData):
     pass;
```

Now, I am trying to get a list of all child classes of masterData. I
have tried:

```
masterData.__subclasses__()
```

The very interesting thing that I found about the above is that it
works flawlessly in *python manage.py shell* and does **not** work at all
when running the webserver!

**So how do I get a list of models derived from an Abstract Base Class model?**

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the error you're getting when you load the page?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. Are the child models in apps that are included in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yeah, @DanielRoseman, the child models are in the same app as MasterData and are included.<br/> jknupp, I just get an empty list when doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Metaclass for defining Abstract Base Classes (ABCs).

Use this metaclass to create an ABC. An ABC can be subclassed directly, and then acts as a mix-in 
class. You can also register unrelated concrete classes (even built-in classes) and unrelated ABCs 
as 'virtual subclasses' -- these and their descendants will be considered subclasses of the 
registering ABC by the built-in issubclass() function, but the registering ABC won't show up in 
their MRO (Method Resolution Order) nor will method implementations defined by the registering 
ABC be callable (not even via super()).
```

I haven't used ABCMeta much (have a bit today actually..). You need to use the 'issubclass()' function
since the ABC won't show up in they're mro.

If you used inheritance, **subclasses**() would work.

```
>>> class foo(object):
...      pass
... 
>>> class bar(foo):
...      pass
... 
>>> a = bar()
>>> a.__class__.__mro__
(<class '__main__.bar'>, <class '__main__.foo'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> foo.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.bar'>]
```

Comment: But how to do this in Django ? I am just not getting foo.__subclasses__() when I use the development server ?